# Python exec grep

Tags: python, exec, subprocess, grep

I'm trying to grep a list of file from the "*.nasl" of "Openvas" which contains a certain port's number.

I can make it directly in the terminal with the command :

```
egrep --only-match '111' /home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/*.nasl |cut -d ":" -f1
```

This command return all the name of the nasl file which contains 111.
like :

```
/home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/SolarWinds_TFTP.nasl:111 
/home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/trojan_horses.nasl:111
```

and after the cut :

```
/home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/SolarWinds_TFTP.nasl
/home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/trojan_horses.nasl
```

But when I'm in python(3.1.3) the output give me an error :
`egrep:/home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/*.nasl: No such file or directory`

i was thinking about a problem because of the "*.nasl" but when I'm trying with an existing file, same result.

Here is the part of code :

```
command = ("egrep --only-match '"+ str(port[0]) +"'  "+ openvas_directory["locate"]["nasl"] + '*.nasl' + ' |cut -d ":" -f1 ')
process=sp.Popen(command,shell=True, stdout= sp.PIPE)
```

or

```
exec(command)
```

I was thinking too of a bad construction but wen I'm printing the command it gives me what i want :

```
egrep --only-match '111' /home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/*.nasl |cut -d ":" -f1
```

If there are any idea!

Comment: `shell=False` never `True` if you're giving a list. `True` is for a command string and not a list.

Comment: I don't think you can pipe commands in a single `Popen` as you are now.

Comment: Ok, i've modified this point ! And with or without the pipe, the result is the same.

Comment: Yes you can pipe `Popen` strings, you just can't use `|` anywhere unless you're opening a shell within your Popen exec which is counter productive (but possible). Did my solution help @G.M ?

Comment: nope >< But i'll use false now :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
x = Popen('egrep --only-match \'111\' /home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/*.nasl', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
y = Popen('cut -d ":" -f1', stdin=x.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

for row in y.stdout.readline():
    print row
```

Or just use `check_output()`
And this is btw how you `|` in Popen ;)

**Guidelines:**

When using `Popen`, if you supply a command as a string, use `shell=True`.
If you however supply `Popen` with a list `['ls, '-l']` then use `shell=False`, that's just how it works.

If you're piping data, execute two different `Popen`'s and use the output from the first command as stdin for the second command, this is equivilant to doing `|` in Linux.

Comment: hum, the solution looks like better but give me the same :     "raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory "

Comment: Odd, i tend to get that when i have syntax errors.
Try `print(['egrep --on.... | cut -d ":" -f1'])` and see what you get when running that command manually. Normally it's a syntax error with the escaping of the `'` or something as such.

Comment: I've already done it with my solution, and the output of the print can be use manually and it's the same with your solution :-/ it gives me : egrep --only-match '111' /home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/*.nasl

Comment: Strangely, when my command is only ='egrep --only-matching' it gives me the same error 'no such...' why not the usage of egrep for not indicate a target ?

Comment: @G.M Have you tried not using `*.nasl* with my solution? it might be it?

Comment: Yes I’ve tried with an existing file which contain the port and no such file.

Comment: @G.M Try it without `--only-match \'111\'`

Comment: already done >< : `x = Popen('grep /home/gwvm/Openvas/var/lib/openvas/plugins/trojan_horses.nasl', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)`   `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I will shit bricks for this, `shell=True` works right? with that command you just pasted.

Comment: huh ! yes it gives me a result, a list of number, not an error :-D Thanks a lot !

Comment: Edited my answer. You're welcome, if you think your issue is solved please mark the answer as correct/answered :) Gl with your programming!